# Custom Mdadm email msg

Tags: raid, email, mdadm

Is it possible to customize the email message from the mdadm monitor process to include custom user text such as "if you get this msg call me!"

Answer (score 0):

If at the end of `/etc/mdadm.conf` you add the following line:

```
PROGRAM /etc/mdadm_warning.sh
```

And create the file `/etc/mdadm_warning.sh` with the following contents:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

event=$1
device=$2

echo "$event on $device" | /usr/bin/mailx -s "RAID Notice" some@email.com
```

Hopefully this is helpful.

You can add checks for specific events and customize the output for each case.  For example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

event=$1
device=$2

if [ $event == "Fail" ];
then
    message="if you get this msg call me!"
else
    message="$event on $device"
fi

echo $message | /usr/bin/mailx -s "RAID Notice" some@email.com
```

No guarantee this will not break with an update.

Probably a good idea to add the original message in every time just in case.